# How can I attach multiple pdfs to drupal_mail() function?

Tags: 7, files, emails

Was doing something like this

```
        global $base_url;
        $uri = $base_url . '/sites/default/files/test.pdf';
        if(!empty($mail_content)) {
            /*send mail */
            $to =$mail_content['to'];       //gets the current user's mail address
            $from = variable_get('site_mail', '');    //admin's mail address
            $body = $mail_content['body'];

            $filemime = $mail_content['mime'];
            $filename = $mail_content['filename'];
            //$filepath = 
            //$filealtname  = drupal_basename($filearray['uri'], $suffix = NULL);

                $attachment = array(
                'filecontent' => 'http://localhost/cando/sites/default/files/test.pdf',
                'filename' => $filename,
                'filemime' => $filemime,
            ); 

            $mail_content['params']['attachments'][] = $attachment;
            $params = array(
                'subject' => $mail_content['subject'],
                'body' => $body,
                'attachment'=>$attachment,
            );

             // print_r($attachment);print_r($params);exit;
        //  print_r(file_get_contents(DRUPAL_ROOT));die;
            $message = drupal_mail('cando_custom', $mail_content['mkey'], $to, language_default(),$params,$from); 

            return 'Mail Sent ... ';

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add headers to the params array.

I did something like :

```
$attachment = array(
      'filecontent' => $filepathname,
      'filename' => $namefile,
      'filemime' => 'application/pdf'
      );
//where $filepathname should contain the path to the file and $filename should contain the name of the file.

$params = array(
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'text/html'),
  'key' => 'test',
  'to' => 'test@example.com',
  'from' => 'test@example.com',
  'subject' => 'Test email',
  'body' => 'test',
  'attachment' => $attachment
);

drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);
```

which worked for me.

In your case:

1. Check the value of $filemime variable.
2. Add headers to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can attach multiple attachments to an e-mail:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch($key) {     
    case 'test1':
      $message['subject'] = 'Hello World';
      $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $params['attachment'];
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $params['attachment2'];          


      break;

    case 'test2':
      $message['subject'] = 'Hello Kitty';
      $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $params['attachment'];
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $params['attachment2'];          


      break;      
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {

        $attachment = array(
            'filecontent' => file_get_contents($node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']),
            'filename' => $node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['filename'],
            'filemime' => $node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['filemime'],
        ); 

        $attachment2 = array(
            'filecontent' => file_get_contents($node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['uri']),
            'filename' => $node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['filename'],
            'filemime' => $node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['filemime'],
        ); 


        $params = array(
            'body' => 'cool',
            'attachment'=> $attachment,
            'attachment2'=> $attachment2,
        );

       $to = $node->field_enter_email[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

       if($something){

           drupal_mail('mymodule', $key = 'test1', $to, language_default(), $params, $from = 'admin@yourdomain.com', $send = TRUE); 

       }
       else {

           drupal_mail('mymodule', $key = 'test2', $to, language_default(), $params, $from = 'admin@yourdomain.com', $send = TRUE); 

       } 

}
```

Comment: Only posting code puts your answer at risk to be deleted via moderation. Maybe add a few comments to briefly explain the "clue" of it (for those who don't get it right away)?